# Activity's OnCreate() not called, how is this possible?

Tags: android, debugging

I am trying to set a breakpoint inside an Activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText htmlContent = null;
    private Button getBtn = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  // <<<< this is where I set a breakpoint

        htmlContent = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.htmlContent);
        getBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.get);
        // anonymous inner class implementing OnClickListener
        getBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // fill htmlContent using HTTP GET
                try {
                  final TestHttpGet thgObj = new TestHttpGet();
                  thgObj.executeHttpGet();
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    // do something meaningful here
                }
            }});

        // start some activity here?
        getBtn.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Now, the funny thing is that this program **runs** and I can even see its layout screen in the emulator, but when I click the getBtn nothing happens, and so I tried to set a breakpoint inside to see why.

The amazing thing is... No breakpoint is ever reached - even if I set it on the first statement in OnCreate(). How is this possible???

Comment: Try a few `Log.d()` and see if it shows up in logcat.

Comment: Maybe mine is a stupid question, but... Are you running the program normally? or using the debug button?

Comment: @Cristian No your question is not stupid at all. *I* am the stupid one... I can't believe I was using Ctrl+F11 instead of F11. Please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe mine is a stupid question, but... Are you running the program normally? or using the debug button?

[image]

Comment: I have no doubt in my mind that many will find this answer useful.